# structured array and search

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need some suggestions for solving this problem. I have this data structure:

```
type
  QmyArray = array of integer;
  PmyArray = record
    element: Qmyarray;
    value: integer;
  end;
  TMyArray = array of Pmyarray;

var
  myarray: tmyArray;
  myvalue: qmyarray;
```

I set all values of myarray correctly, and all values of myarray.element are sorted correctly and this is fine. The problem I have is when I want search myvalue in myarray and get value.
For searching, I use binarysearch and write:

```
tarray.BinarySearch(myarray, myvalue, index);
```

and of course it's not working. Because I understood that need customized the comparer so I write:

```
function CompareB(const Left, Right: integer): Integer;
begin
  if Left < Right then
    Result := -1
  else if Left > Right then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function CompareA(const Left, Right: pmyarray): Integer;
var
  iIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareB(Left.element[0], Right.element[0]);
  for iIndex := 1 to High(Right.element) do
    if Result = 0 then
      Result := CompareB(Left.element[iIndex], Right.element[iIndex]);
end;
```

and try with:

```
tarray.BinarySearch(myarray, myvalue, index, TComparer<Pmyarray>.Construct(CompareA));
```

but in this case I receive this error:

> [DCC Error] Project1.dpr(98): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'BinarySearch' that can be called with these arguments

and I don't understand where I made a mistake.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This looks like a dictionary to me......

Comment: Yes, infact. Looking example of some days ago, i thinked that is better. Just only i have had some doubt. becouse with array with much elements (in order of million) for read all it, i take 4-5 secs, and with list until a 20-25 seconds. If dictionary help me with less time then it is very good for me too.

Answer (score 4):

You have one sole error, the type of the `myvalue` variable should be `PMyArray`, not `QmyArray`. Next time you're facing such a problem try using the long-hand version of `TArray.BinarySearch`, so that Code Insight actually shows meaningful type names.

When you write:

```
TArray.BinarySearch(myarray, myvalue, index, iComparer)
```

the compiler needs to guess the type of your array from the parameters. If you missmatch the types of `myarray` and `myvalue` the compiler can't tell what you really wanted and code insight has no chance of actually showing you what it wants. But you can give it a hand by telling it the type of array you want to operate on, using this syntax:

```
TArray.BinarySearch<PmyArray>(myarray, myvalue, index, iComparer)
```

With this, the compiler knows you intend to deal with an array of `PmyArray`. Code insight also knows that and shows you the exact types of parameters it needs.

This works:

```
program Project9;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections, Generics.Defaults;

type
  QmyArray = array of Integer;
  PmyArray = record
    element: QmyArray;
    value: Integer;
  end;
  TMyArray = array of PmyArray;

var myarray: TMyArray;
    myvalue: PmyArray;
    FoundIndex: Integer;

function CompareB(const Left, Right: integer): Integer;
begin
  if Left < Right then
    Result := -1
  else if Left > Right then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

function CompareA(const Left, Right: pmyarray): Integer;
var
  iIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareB(Left.element[0], Right.element[0]);
  for iIndex := 1 to High(Right.element) do
    if Result = 0 then
      Result := CompareB(Left.element[iIndex], Right.element[iIndex]);
end;

begin
  TArray.BinarySearch<PmyArray>(myarray, myvalue, FoundIndex, TComparer<PmyArray>.Construct(CompareA));
end.
```

Comment: Hello, your example solve the problem but just in part; in input i have a variable of type qmyarray and i need search this value in array for get value associated in array.

Comment: You don't actually have a choice, the `TArray.BinarySearch<T>` searches an `array of T` for a value of type `T`. In your case you'll simply need to declare a variable of type `PMyArray`, init it's `element` field with what you need and search for that.